# How to Pass parameters to batch file using Echo by java

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, echo

i've a java application that takes 2 parameters and i want to make batch file .bat to run the jar file
i want to pass the parameters to the jar file using the echo command
so if i clicked on the .bat file then a message telling

please enter the first parameter

after pressing enter another message appears

please enter the second parameter

at the end these 2 parameters will be passed to the jar file

java -jar MathCalculations.jar firstParameter seconedParameter

any recommendations how to write this batch file please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution:

```
@echo off
set /P "Parameter1=Please enter first parameter: "
set /P "Parameter2=Please enter second parameter: "
java.exe -jar MathCalculations.jar "%Parameter1%" "%Parameter2%"
```

Enter in a command prompt window either `set /?` or `help set` for more information.

Please note that the user of the batch file can just hit ENTER or RETURN without entering anything. You may define default values for this case like

```
@echo off
set "Parameter1=Default Option 1"
set /P "Parameter1=Please enter first parameter: "
set "Parameter2=Default Option 2"
set /P "Parameter2=Please enter second parameter: "
java.exe -jar MathCalculations.jar "%Parameter1%" "%Parameter2%"
```